# iteratively assign objects with similar names as function arguments, getting rid of -eval(parse())-

Tags: r, function, apply

Suppose I have:

```
a_1 <- 2
a_2 <- 5
a_3 <- 7

my.foo <- function (input) {print(input^2)}
```

My aim is to pass all the objects with a name starting with `a_` as `my.foo()` arguments (hence in the example `a_1`, `a_2` and `a_3`).

The Following code works as expected:

```
n <- length(ls(pattern = "a_")) 

for (i in 1:n) {  
    A <- paste("a_",i,sep="")
    my.foo(input=eval(parse(text=A)))
}
```

My feeling is that this is not really "elegant".. it is like "forcing" R to do what I could do with Stata in a way easier way (through macro variables).

I wonder whether there is a more direct way to address the issue. I tried to put `a_1`, `a_2` and `a_3` in a list object and then to use `apply` functions, but without much success.

Thanks, 
Stefano

Comment: Your feeling is correct.  R is indeed designed around putting your data in a list or other structure.  An atomic vector may be what you want here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
my.foo <- function (input) input^2
sapply(ls(pattern = "a_"), function(x) my.foo(get(x)))
# a_1 a_2 a_3 
#   4  25  49 
sapply(list(a_1, a_2, a_3), my.foo)
# [1]  4 25 49
```

I removed the `print` from your function because it results in double printing with these examples.

Comment: Or even `my.foo(c(a_1, a_2, a_3))`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I took that to be obvious and was showing how one of the `apply` family of functions could be used with lists.

Comment: Then again, one should probably never take things as obvious for Stata users coming to R :-)

Comment: Also, if the values in the "a_" objects are themselves vectors with `length` > 1, there's a difference in how `list(.)` and `c(.)` would perform in this case.

Comment: The fact that the "a_" objects are all of length 1 and related by name leads me to think that he may want an atomic vector.

Comment: may I also ask you what is the difference if the `a_` objects are lists?

Comment: @Stezzo, can you give an example? If you need to recursively apply a function, then you might need to look at `rapply` or consider `unlist`ing the values first.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, suppose that `my.foo2 <- function (z,w) z+w` and `list_1 <- list(1, 10)`, `list_2 <- list(5, 20)`. For each `list_` object I'd like to pass its two elements as the arguments of `my.foo2` (in the most general case I don't know how many `list_` objects exist). I was trying to put all the `list_` elements together in a bigger list and work from there but can't figure out how to do what I  want to through `apply` or `rapply`. Many thanks

Comment: @Stezzo, totally different question! (But since it's easy to answer, I'll answer it here: `mapply(my.foo2, list_1, list_2)`.

Comment: you're right! I was thinking to put it as a brand new one rather than an edit or a comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AnandaMahto see also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170461/iteratively-assigning-lists-elements-as-function-arguments] for a clearer explanation of my last comment. Thanks, Stefano