# assigning lists elements as function arguments

Tags: r, function, mapply

Suppose that:

```
list_a <- list(1, 10)
list_2 <- list(5, 20)

my.foo <- function (z,w) z+w
```

My main question is: for each `list_` object, how to pass its two elements as the arguments of `my.foo` so that to obtain 11 and 25?

My closest guess to solve the problem so far is:

```
mapply(my.foo, list_a, list_2)
```

but it is not suited for what I need to do, as it returns 6 and 30.

Thanks for any suggestions,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ls` and `get` to get the objects and `do.call` to call your function with the content of the objects as arguments:

```
sapply(ls(pattern="list_*"), function(x) do.call(my.foo, get(x)))
# list_2 list_a 
#     25     11
```

If you instead wanted to provide a list of objects to operate on:

```
objs <- list(list_a, list_2)
unlist(lapply(objs, function(x) do.call(my.foo, x)))
# [1] 11 25
```

Comment: The second option is the one I was also trying to work on, thanks! Stefano